# CSSComb in VSC not working with :root selector

Tags: visual-studio-code, typeerror, csscomb

I am using Visual Studio Code where I have the CSScomb plugin installed.

When I try to use the selector :root and execute CSScomb I get the message:

```
[CSSComb]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of null
```

what does it mean and how can I fix this?

Thank you!